# How to delete elements from an array from different indexes by single method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write the logic to delete element by passing indexArr(that contains indexes to delete) to a method:

```js
var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
Array.prototype.removeElem = function(indexArr){
 this.filter(function(value,index,arr){
  return indexArr.indexOf(index)>-1 ? arr[index] = undefined:false
   }
 });
}

a.removeElem([2,3]); //passing indexes in form of array
console.log(a.join('').split('')); //removing undefined values
```

As you can see, I am removing `undefined` values after the execution of `removeElem()` method, but I want to do that in the method itself.

Comment: If you expect `.removeElem()` to mutate the array it's called on, the simplest solution is to rewrite it using a for loop and `.splice()`, so that it can actually remove elements from the `this` array. The `.filter()` method doesn't modify the `this` array, it creates a new array; if you're not using its return value you should be using `.forEach()`. (If you *were* using its return value the callback to `filter()` could be a one-liner like `return indexArr.indexOf(index)>-1;`.)

Comment: not able to do that with splice, beacuse splice modifies the array

Comment: I said "If you expect `.removeElem()` to mutate the array it's called on", which seems to be the way you're using it in the code shown. If you want `.removeElem()` to return a *new* array then you can definitely use `.filter()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify an original array, you can use `while()` loop from last to first index combined with `splice()` method:

```js
var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

Array.prototype.removeElem = function(indexArr){
  var length = this.length;
  while(length--) {
    if(indexArr.indexOf(length) > -1) {
      this.splice(length, 1);
    }
  }
}


console.log(a.removeElem([0,1]));
console.log(a);
```

Comment: I think the OP expects the `.removeElem()` method to mutate the array it is called on (like `.splice()` does).

Comment: i want to pass index in removeElem not value

Comment: I misunderstood first time. Edited now, enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

```js
var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
Array.prototype.removeElem = function(indexArr){
    indexArr.sort();
    i=indexArr.length;
    while(i--)
    {
     a.splice(indexArr[i],1);
    }
}

a.removeElem([2,3]); //passing indexes in form of array
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't remove the specified elements. (Output in your example should be `[0,1,4,5]`.)

Comment: i am asking different thing, your code is changing the array, please check

Comment: OP is asked to remove indices and my code will remove specified index from the array

Comment: no @Dilip, when you remove the element at second index, arr becomes [0,1,3,4,5], then you are removing the 3 index, so you are removing 4, but expected answer should be [0,1,4,5] not [0,1,3,5]

Comment: After you remove the first element, you use indexes on the changed array, not on the original. Otherwise how would you get item '4' removed if you pass indexes 2 and 3?

Comment: oops! my bad, wait I will modify my answer

Comment: I edited the answer, now it will work as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `Array.filter()`. Try something like this :

```js
let a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
Array.prototype.removeElem = function(indexArr) {
    let removedElem = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < indexArr.length; i++) {
        this.splice(indexArr[i] - removedElem, 1)
        removedElem += 1;
    };
    return this;
}
console.log(a.removeElem([2, 3]));
```

simple :)

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of reduce for this.

check the following code snippet

```js
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
Array.prototype.removeElem = function(indexArr) {
  return this.reduce((result, key, index) => {
    if (indexArr.indexOf(index) === -1) {
      result.push(key)
    }
    return result
  }, [])
}


var result = a.removeElem([2, 3]); //passing indexes in form of array

console.log(result.join('').split(''));
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

use splice method to add and remove element from array

Comment: i want to remove multiple elements